# First time using react. How to get rss items into a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rss

This is the first time I am using react. I am coming from jQuery to React this feels like a big jump. If anybody can help me refactor this to work the React way I will be forever in your debt! :)

I am trying to parse an RSS feed, where I want to grab the most recent post title and link to render into a component.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser - Using this to get the parser.

When viewing my app in the browser the async function is spitting out the rss feed into the console, which is a good start I guess!

```
    // src/App/index.tsx
    import * as React from 'react';
    import * as Parser from 'rss-parser';
    // Types
    import { string } from 'prop-types';

    let parser = new Parser();

    // blueprint for the properties
    interface Props {
      name: string;
    }

    // Component state
    interface State {
        //feed: any[];
    }


    (async () => {

      let feed = await parser.parseURL('https://www.reddit.com/.rss');
      console.log(feed.title);

      feed.items.forEach((item: { title: string; link: string; }) => {
        console.log(item.title + ':' + item.link)
      });

    })();


    export default class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>RSS Feed</h1>
            <div>
              <h1>item.title</h1>
              <a href="">item.link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Read up lifecycle methods and state - fetch on mount and set the data to state, conditionally render if the data is present in state

Comment: I'm getting error BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you right, you need something like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
         super(props);
         this.state = { feed: [] };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const feed = await parser.parseURL('https://www.reddit.com/.rss');
        this.setState({ feed });
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <h1>RSS Feed</h1>
            this.state.feed.map((item, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <h1>item.title</h1>
                    <a href="">item.link</a>
                </div>
            ))
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved by this. if you don't check for "undefined" value. It will show you error because react renders page 2 times and you have an undefined array of `feed.items` in your hand when in first render.

My index.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom';

let Parser = require('rss-parser');
let parser = new Parser();
const CORS_PROXY = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      feed: []
     };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const feed = await parser.parseURL(CORS_PROXY + 'https://www.reddit.com/.rss');
    this.setState(feed)
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>      
      
      <h1>Blog Posts</h1>
      
     
      {this.state.items && this.state.items.map((items, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <h1>{items.title}</h1>
                    <a href="">{items.link}</a>
                </div>
      ))}

    </div>
    );
  }
}

render(
  <App />, 
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```